# Creating SOAP request and signing the payload

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to call a Web Service with PHP Soap, and I'm having trouble creating the request and signing it properly.

I'm doing it like this:

```
$docRequest = new DomDocument();

$docRequest->loadXML(
  '<ApplicationRequest xmlns="http://bxd.fi/xmldata/">
     <CustomerId>123</CustomerId>
   </ApplicationRequest>');

$doc = signXML($docRequest);

$params = array(
  'RequestHeader' => array(
    'SenderId' => 456,
    'RequestId' => 1111
  ),
  'ApplicationRequest' => $doc->saveXML()
);

$client = new SignSoapClient($wsdl);
$client->__soapCall($soap_function, array($params));
```

Which results in this:

```
<RequestHeader>
  <SenderId>456</SenderId>
  <RequestId>1111</RequestId>
</RequestHeader>
<ApplicationRequest>
  <ApplicationRequest xmlns="http://bxd.fi/xmldata/">
    <CustomerId>123</CustomerId>
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      ...
    </Signature>
  </ApplicationRequest>
</ApplicationRequest>
```

So the question is, how do I sign the $docRequest like now, and then add it to $params without the second ApplicationRequest tag?
OR
If I were to create it in this manner:

```
$params = array(
  'RequestHeader' => array(
    ...
  ),
  'ApplicationRequest' => '<CustomerId>123</CustomerId>'
);
```

Can I sign just the ApplicationRequest inside the complete XML later on just before signing the SOAP itself? (Using wse-php and the SOAP message is signed in `SignSoapClient`'s `__doRequest()`)

Comment: Don't answer this. Problems are solved and this question was totally irrelevant. Turns out it is really important not to create a new private key, and then use it to sign the request while still using the certificate acquired with the original private key.